# Map an array of N strings to an array of arrays (of N/b strings)

Tags: scala

Say we have an array of strings, e.g.,

```
val arr1: Array[String] = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
```

Is there any elegant way I can map this array to an Array of b arrays each? For simplicity, I guess it's possible to assume that b is divisible by the length of arr1.

For instance, the length of arr1 is 6, and for groups of b = 2, the result should be:

```
    Array( Array("a","b"), Array("c,d"), Array("e,f") )
```

Any strategies or hints are much appreciated!

Comment: `arr1.grouped(2).toArray`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No strategies or hints required, there is a built-in function for this:

```
val b = 2;

arr1.grouped(b).toArray
```

If `b` is not a multiple of the array size then the last element will have fewer than `b` values. If the array is empty, the result is also empty.